# MarkLogic Node.js. "Or" query Not working

Tags: marklogic

I have two range indexes and I am trying to run below **"OR"** query which does a wild card search. But it is not returning results.

**Does not work.The below query returns empty array:**

```
 db.documents.query(qb.where(
            qb.or(
                qb.word(qb.range('informationProviderName'), 'a*'),
                qb.word(qb.range('functionalName'), 'a*')
        )).withOptions({ categories: ['metadata'] })
        ) 
        .result(function (documents) {
            res.json(documents);
        }, function (error) {
            console.dir(error);
        });
```

But when I execute the query individually, it returns the results.

**Works:**

```
  db.documents.query(qb.where(
                qb.word(qb.range('informationProviderName'), 'a*')
            ).withOptions({ categories: ['metadata'] })
        )
        .result(function (documents) {
            res.json(documents);
        }, function (error) {
            console.dir(error);
        });
```

**Works:**

```
db.documents.query(qb.where(
            qb.word(qb.range('functionalName'), 'a*')
        ).withOptions({ categories: ['metadata'] })
    )
    .result(function (documents) {
        res.json(documents);
    }, function (error) {
        console.dir(error);
    });
```

**Please help?**

Correct Answer: As per the comment:

```
return qb.where(qb.or(
        qb.word(qb.field('productName'), 'a*'),
            qb.word(qb.field('manufacturerName'), 'a*')
    ));
```

Comment: I am not even able to execute a simple "OR" query. It does not return results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of things to look at. First, the QueryBuilder.word function takes a string or IndexedName (like what is returned from QueryBuilder.element or QueryBuilder.property). You are passing QueryBuilder.range which returns a Query type, not an IndexedName type.

A few other things of note is that you'll want to check the following indexes on your database to ensure they are enabled: "three character searches", "fast element character searches", "one character searches", and "two character searches". You will notice that there is a warning associated with each of "slower document loads and larger database files." Depending on your needs, you may decide that the "three character searches" is all you need and that you'll just wait until you have at least three characters to send to the query.